# Understand Vectors use

Tags: three.js

From my physics studies a vector is similar to an arrow, it has, in 3-dimensional space, 3 coordinates (x,y,z), a magnitude, a direction (cosines).
In three.js you can define Vector3 just by 3 coordinates. Is in three.js a Vector3 object like a point in space?

Comment: Why complicate things? Might be the type Point3, but all the same many prototypes have been inherited from the Vector3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In three.js, the `Vector3` class can be interpreted as representing either a 3D point, or a 3D direction vector emanating from the origin.

Be careful, though. Direction vectors, when used as arguments in three.js methods, are assumed to be normalized -- that is, of unit length.

three.js has a method for that: `Vector3.normalize()`.

By the way, there is also the `Ray` class, which represents the construct from your physics studies.

three.js r.71

Comment: so if I do `var vector = new THREE.Vector3(2,2,2); vector.normalize();` is the same as doing `var vector = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1)`  ??

Answer (score 2):

You may note from your physics class, that a vector can be translated with no effect on the vector.

[image: vectors]

The vectors above are identical, so its easier to just assume the vector starts at the origin, and refer to it by the location of its head.

A Vector3 in three.js is just the coordinates of the head, and that represents both direction and magnitude all in one.

That said, we often use it in an abstract way to also represent 3D points in space too, but the data presentation is the same (3 numbers), so we just use the same Vector3 class.